# non-static method getHostServices() cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have this JavaFX code which calls e-mail client

```
        MenuItem ri = new MenuItem("Report Issue");

        // Start E-Mail Client with E-Mail template and send E-Mail
        ri.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e)
            {


                Application.getHostServices().showDocument("mailto:"+textField.getText());



            }
        });
```

I get message in Netbeans `non-static method getHostServices() cannot be referenced from a static context`

Can you tell me how I can solve this?

P.S this is the solution that I can managed to create:

```
ri.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e)
            {

                Application a = new Application() {

                    @Override
                    public void start(Stage stage)
                    {
                    }
                };
                final TextField textField = new TextField("help@example.com");
                a.getHostServices().showDocument("mailto:"+textField.getText());

            }
        });
```

Any better proposals?

Comment: Well what would you expect it to do? Do you understand the error? Look at all the related questions.

Comment: You get a large amount of very similar questions and answer by googling your exact question.

Comment: It's not a static method. Call it on the Application object, not on the class.

Comment: I don't know how to make it any clearer. Just use a reference to an Application object, not the class name.

Answer (score 4):

I use code in this way:

```
public class App extends Application {
    private static App mInstance;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { launch(args); }

    public static App getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        // your code
    }
}
```

and you can get it anywhere in your app like this

```
HostServices services = App.getInstance().getHostServices();
services.showDocument(url);
```

Comment: Where is private static App mInstance initialized anyway?

Answer (score 2):

looks like getHostServices()  is not a static method defined in Application class or its subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to instantiate your Application class to use the method in a non-static context:

Application a = new Application();
a.getHostServices().showDocument("mailto:"+textField.getText());

or if you want to run this program in a static context, change your getHostServices() method:

public void getHostServices(){...}  
 to something like
public static void getHostServices(){...}

(edit)
as James points out my answer was nonsense for FX; you cannot modify Application, and instantiating does not make any sense.
If your program extends Application then try to simply remove "Application." from your first code as your program inherits the getHostServices() method.

Comment: As this is a JavaFX question, it seems likely the OP is referring to the javafx.application.Application class. This class shouldn't be instantiated by the developer but by the JavaFX framework.

Comment: so "getHostServices().showDocument("mailto:"+textField.getText());" is the solution (provided the program extends Application)

Answer (score -1):

well make getHostServices a static method if it suites your design, or make an arrangement to call it from a non-static method or block.

Comment: for example : if your method is defined as "public <return type> getHostServices(parameter list) { body }". Just change it to "public static <return type> getHostServices(parameter list) { body } and see if the error is gone.

Comment: getHostServices is a (non-static, obviously) API method in the Application class, so this answer doesn't really apply.